# Regular expression for a language tag (as defined by BCP47)

Tags: regex, bnf

I need a regular expression for a [language tag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IETF_language_tag) as defined by [BCP 47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt).

I know that the full BNF syntax is available at http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt and that I could use it to write my own, but hopefully there is one already out there.

Comment: Haha. I did this for myself a couple of weeks ago, but unfortunately my disk (which was a brand new SSD) died. I'll take a look again :)

Comment: @PaulPRO: Language tags are most definitely regular.

Comment: If you don't need a regex as comprehensive as this, but are rather just looking for something that will capture the majority of commonly-used locales [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300605/296725).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like this:

```
^((?<grandfathered>(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|
i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)|(art-lojban|
cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang))|((?<language>
([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-(?<extlang>[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})
(-(?<script>[A-Za-z]{4}))?(-(?<region>[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(-(?<variant>[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}
|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(-(?<extension>[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*
(-(?<privateUse>x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?)|(?<privateUse>x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))$
```

Here is the code to generate it (in C#):

```
var regular = "(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang)";
var irregular = "(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)";
var grandfathered = "(?<grandfathered>" + irregular + "|" + regular + ")";
var privateUse = "(?<privateUse>x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+)";
var singleton = "[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z]";
var extension = "(?<extension>" + singleton + "(-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+)";
var variant = "(?<variant>[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3})";
var region = "(?<region>[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3})";
var script = "(?<script>[A-Za-z]{4})";
var extlang = "(?<extlang>[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2})";
var language = "(?<language>([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-" + extlang + ")?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})";
var langtag = "(" + language + "(-" + script + ")?" + "(-" + region + ")?" + "(-" + variant + ")*" + "(-" + extension + ")*" + "(-" + privateUse + ")?" + ")";
var languageTag = @"^(" + grandfathered + "|" + langtag + "|" + privateUse + ")$";

Console.WriteLine(languageTag);
```

I cannot guarantee its correctness (I may have made typos), but it works fine on the examples in Appendix A.

Depending on your environment, you might need to remove the named capturing groups `"?<...>"`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Works great with PHP after making a few changes. I was asking myself, what do those 'named capturing groups' do? This isn't a feature available in PHP's regex syntax as far as I know, but I'm just interested.

Comment: @Tim It just allows you to access groups by name rather than index. e.g. `match.Groups["variant"]`

Comment: I don't think this will resolve the "regular grandfathered" sections properly (they'll be parsed as a normal tag rather than the special code that they are).
You'll need to place the `grandfathered` variable before the `langtag` variable during the definition of `languageTag`

Comment: @GrantPeters: you're correct; there are 9 items that match either way (art-lojban, cel-gaulish, no-bok, no-nyn, zh-guoyu, zh-hakka, zh-min, zh-min-nan, zh-xiang). I'll update so grandfathered tags come first

Comment: TypeScript complains that the `privateUse` capture group name is used twice. Could you fix this?

Answer (score 5):

An optimized version that works in PHP.

```
/(\A(?<grandfathered>(?:en-GB-oed|i-(?:ami|bnn|default|enochian|hak|klingon|lux|mingo|navajo|pwn|t(?:a[oy]|su))|sgn-(?:BE-(?:FR|NL)|CH-DE))|(?:art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-(?:bok|nyn)|zh-(?:guoyu|hakka|min(?:-nan)?|xiang)))|(?:(?<language>(?:[A-Za-z]{2,3}(?:-(?<extlang>[A-Za-z]{3}(?:-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})(?:-(?<script>[A-Za-z]{4}))?(?:-(?<region>[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(?:-(?<variant>[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(?:-(?<extension>[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*)(?:-(?<privateUse>x(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?\z)?/Di
```

Comment: This whole regex should be enclosed in non matching group, otherwise bad formatted tags like "abcdefghi" are matched by it, because "^" is applied only for the <grandfathered> group.

Comment: Thanks @Smilediver, I also switched from `^` and `$` to `\A` and `\z` respectively. This ensures that we don't allow any kind of whitespace anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript polices duplicate named capture groups so you have to change the 2nd use of `?<privateUse>` to e.g. `?<privateUse1>`. Compiles to:

```
/^((?<grandfathered>(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)|(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang))|((?<language>([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-(?<extlang>[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2}))?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})(-(?<script>[A-Za-z]{4}))?(-(?<region>[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?(-(?<variant>[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3}))*(-(?<extension>[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z](-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+))*(-(?<privateUse>x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))?)|(?<privateUse1>x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+))$/
```

Here's a way to construct it:

```
let privateUseUsed = 0
const privateUse = () => "(?<privateUse" + (privateUseUsed++) + ">x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+)"
const grandfathered = "(?<grandfathered>" +
      /* irregular */ (
        "en-GB-oed" +
          "|" + "i-(?:ami|bnn|default|enochian|hak|klingon|lux|mingo|navajo|pwn|tao|tay|tsu)" +
          "|" + "sgn-(?:BE-FR|BE-NL|CH-DE)"
      ) +
      "|" + /* regular */ (
        "art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang"
      ) +
      ")"
const langtag = "(" +
      "(?<language>" + (
        "([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-" +
          "(?<extlang>[A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2})" +
          ")?)|[A-Za-z]{4,8})"
      ) +
      "(-" + "(?<script>[A-Za-z]{4})" + ")?" +
      "(-" + "(?<region>[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3})" + ")?" +
      "(-" + "(?<variant>[A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3})" + ")*" +
      "(-" + "(?<extension>" + (
        /* singleton */ "[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z]" +
          "(-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+)"
      ) +
      ")*" +
      "(-" + privateUse() + ")?" +
      ")"
const languageTagReStr = "^(" + grandfathered + "|" + langtag + "|" + privateUse() + ")$";
```

Edit: turns out ff doens't support named capture groups so you have to strip them out with `.replace(/\?<a-zA-Z>/g, '')` or jest leave them out in the first place:

```
const grandfathered = "(" +
      /* irregular */ "(en-GB-oed|i-ami|i-bnn|i-default|i-enochian|i-hak|i-klingon|i-lux|i-mingo|i-navajo|i-pwn|i-tao|i-tay|i-tsu|sgn-BE-FR|sgn-BE-NL|sgn-CH-DE)" +
      "|" +
      /* regular */ "(art-lojban|cel-gaulish|no-bok|no-nyn|zh-guoyu|zh-hakka|zh-min|zh-min-nan|zh-xiang)" +
      ")";
const langtag = "(" +
      "(" + (
        "([A-Za-z]{2,3}(-" +
          "([A-Za-z]{3}(-[A-Za-z]{3}){0,2})" +
          ")?)|[A-Za-z]{4}|[A-Za-z]{5,8})"
      ) +
      "(-" + "([A-Za-z]{4})" + ")?" +
      "(-" + "([A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3})" + ")?" +
      "(-" + "([A-Za-z0-9]{5,8}|[0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3})" + ")*" +
      "(-" + "(" + (
        /* singleton */ "[0-9A-WY-Za-wy-z]" +
          "(-[A-Za-z0-9]{2,8})+)"
      ) +
      ")*" +
      "(-" + "(x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+)" + ")?" +
      ")";
const languageTag = RegExp("^(" + grandfathered + "|" + langtag + "|" + "(x(-[A-Za-z0-9]{1,8})+)" + ")$");
```

Test with `languageTag.test('en-us')`

Answer (score 0):

If using a CLDR-based function set, like PHP's [`intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension, you can check if a locale exists in the `intl` database using a function like:

```
<?php
 function is_locale($locale=''){
  // STANDARDISE INPUT
  $locale=locale_canonicalize($locale);

  // LOAD ARRAY WITH LOCALES
  $locales=resourcebundle_locales(NULL);

  // RETURN WHETHER FOUND
  return (array_search($locale,$locales)!==F);
 }
?>
```

It takes about half a millisecond to load and search the data, so it won't be too much of a performance hit.

Of course, it will only find those in the database of the CLDR version supplied with the PHP version used, but will be updated with each subsequent PHP release.