# Is there a regex to test if a string is for a locale?

Tags: c#, regex

I don't know anything about regular expressions but I think I have to use it for my probleme I got some filenames that look like :

```
MyResource
MyResource.en-GB
MyResource.en-US
MyResource.fr-FR
MyResource.de-DE
```

The idea is to test if my strings end with "[letter][letter]-[letter][letter]"

I know this is a very noob, but I just have no idea about how to do it, even if I know exactly what I wanna do... :(

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That would be testing your input against:

```
\.[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$
```

This is really very literal: "match a dot (`\.`, the dot being a special character in regexes), followed by exactly two of any characters from `a` to `z` (`[a-z]{2}` -- `[...]` is a character class), followed by a dash (`-`), followed by two of any characters from `A` to `Z` (`[A-Z]{2}`), followed by the end of input (`$`).

http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match <-- how to apply this regex in C# against an input. It means the code would look like (UNTESTED):

```
// Post edit: this will really return a boolean
if (Regex.Match(input, @"\.[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}$").Success) {
    // there is a match
}
```

http://regex.info <-- buy that and read it, it is the BEST resource for regular expressions in the universe

http://regular-expressions.info <-- the second best resource

Comment: This will only match if "[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}" is the end of the string ? I mean, it won't match "blaaa_ui-gt_blaaa" ?

Comment: Indeed it won't. Note also that is looks for the dot, as well.

Comment: Yep thats good, you hadnt posted the complete answer so I wasnt sure :) Thks !

Comment: Now that I tried it, I got the following error : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' to 'bool'"

Comment: Ok, I added .Success and it's ok ;)

Comment: Please note: **en_150** is valid locale for European English. [link] (http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-22)

Comment: Down-voting this answer:  please do not use this code in production for all locale codes. *es_419* and *en_150* are all valid locale codes; this code will only match locale codes containing alpha characters.

Comment: @Sean OK, fine, then please give the appropriate information instead of just downvoting, will you? Along with references, of course

Comment: As `Parag` alluded to earlier, the correct way of doing this is to avoid pattern matching altogether. It will be difficult to construct a regular expression to match all locale identifiers, especially if they're not canonicalised. My recommendation for the OP is to avoid this entirely and instead use the ICU bindings for .NET C#, create a locale, canonicalise it, and then use the appropriate methods for fetching the language and region components of the locale identifier itself. http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale

Comment: This didn't work with me for `pt-BR`, but `Regex.Match(input, @"[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}").Success` did work.

Comment: Some codes have 3 characters in the second set. https://www.science.co.il/language/Codes.php `\.[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{3}$`

Answer (score 29):

To cater for basic variants:

```
^[A-Za-z]{2,4}([_-][A-Za-z]{4})?([_-]([A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?$
```

which consists of:

1. Language code: [ISO 639](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/codes.asp?order=639_3&letter=%25) 2 or 3, or 4 for future use, alpha.
2. Optional script code: [ISO 15924](http://unicode.org/iso15924/iso15924-codes.html) 4 alpha.
3. Optional country code: [ISO 3166-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) 2 alpha or 3 digit.
4. Separated by underscores or dashes.

Valid examples are:

- de
- en-US
- zh-Hant-TW
- En-au
- aZ_cYrl-aZ.

For the OP's specific question, this would need to be prefixed by `/^MyResource[.]` and suffixed by `$/` to ensure the whole file name is for a valid resource file that ends in a locale.

Note that some programming language's functions may only accept particular forms, like only underscores and uppercase country code. PHP's `intl` functions accept either case and separators. PayPal accepts only the language, or the `la_CY` form, where `la` is the language and `CY` is the country/region. The PHP `locale_canonicalize` function can be used to standardise to this format.

IETF [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#page-5), which governs internet usage of these tags, recommends a capitalisation and separation format like `az-Cyrl-AZ`, as used in the first three examples above, though it says processors should accept any mix of case and either separator, as per the last two examples. When displaying locales on web pages, using `-` as the separator allows finer-grained line-wrapping which might otherwise produce significantly empty lines as when the non-wrapping `_` is used, especially in table cells.

The regex for the recommended basic format is:

```
^[a-z]{2,4}(-[A-Z][a-z]{3})?(-([A-Z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?$
```

The regexp only covers the basic format. There are variants for extras, like local region. [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5646#page-5) allows for such variants, along with private extensions and backwards-compatibility forms. It all depends upon the granularity required. The [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) Unicode database, which is used by PHP's `intl` functions and other programs, may include such variants from version to version, though they can also disappear at a later time.

If using a CLDR-based function set, like PHP's [`intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension, you can check if a locale exists in the `intl` database using a function like:

```
<?php
 function is_locale($locale=''){
  // STANDARDISE INPUT
  $locale=locale_canonicalize($locale);
  
  // LOAD ARRAY WITH LOCALES
  $locales=resourcebundle_locales('');
  
  // RETURN WHETHER FOUND
  return (array_search($locale,$locales)!==F);
 }
?>
```

It takes about half a millisecond to load and search the data, so it won't be too much of a performance hit.

Of course, it will only find those in the database of the CLDR version supplied with the PHP version used, but will be updated with each subsequent PHP release.

Note that some locales are not for countries, but regions, and these are typically numeric, like `001` for 'World', `150` for 'Europe' and `419` for 'Latin America'. So there are now `en-001`, `en-150`, `ar-001`, and `es-419`, which can be used for generic language purposes. For example, `en-001` was designed to decouple dependence upon `en-us` as an ersatz English, especially since its date formats and spellings are radically different from the 100 other regional `en` variants. The `en-150` locale is the same as `en-001` except for numbering separators and other Europe-specific formats.

In general, a regexp is a good front-end sanity check to filter out illegal characters, and especially to reserve the format for possible future additions. It also helps to prevent malicious character combinations being sent to the lookup facility, especially if text-based lookup command mechanisms, like SQL or Xpath, are used.

Comment: Thank you! This is a much saner, easier-to-adopt, yet reasonably comprehensive version than [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7036171/296725).

Comment: This was completely plagiarised, along with bits of other answers to https://newbedev.com/regex-to-detect-locales, with no citation.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than use Regex, I suggest you use the built-in support for cultures in .Net, i.e., the System.Globalization.CultureInfo class; the constructor recognizes valid culture strings, and gives you an object that can be used for culture specific operations:

```
try
{
    string fileName = "MyResource.en-GB";
    string cultureName = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).TrimStart('.');
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    // Invalid culture.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

`[a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2}`

Comment: How do I specify this to be at the end of my string ?

Comment: You propose to try this. Please write a more assertive answer. And did you try it yourself by the way? It does not look like it could match any of the OP-given examples, which all end in two upper case letters. Maybe the one who upvoted this has more insight, but I think that this cannot work....

Answer (score 1):

```
cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(System.Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures);
cultures.Where(o => filename.EndsWith(o.Name));
```

Comment: This really is not what I wanna do.. I want it to test all possible locales...

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered it in the question.  Try:

```
// This basically grabs the locale.
string x = MyResource.whatever....            //Whatever it might be.
string locale = x.SubString(x.Length - 5)     // Assuming the locale is 5 characters long.

// Now you have a 'locale' that is ready for comparisons.
if (locale == "en-GB") { .... }
if (locale == "fr-FR") { .... }
etc....
```

On a similar note, here is a useful list of two letter country codes.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

I know this isn't really regex, but you didn't seem sure about needing to use it absolutely.

Comment: maybe there exists files with length less than 5

Comment: so what, maybe there are dozens of ways for this to go wrong.  I'm just not in the habit of writing bug-proof code for SO questions. :\

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an answer to this question, but one may pass by and be looking for this answer.

To match locales like `en_GB` you can use this expression:

`/^[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}$/`

I'll try to explain it here:

`^[a-z]` means start with lower case letters and `{2}` means you expect exactly 2 of those

follow with `_`

`[A-Z]{2}$` means end with upper case letters and match exactly 2 of those, `$` means that these letters have to be in the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

An extension to [the great answer by Patanjali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48300605/512507), but also including named groups and support for private-use as defined in [RFC 4647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647). For example: `de-DE-x-goethe` or `zh-Hant-CN-x-private1-private2`.

```
^(?<language>[A-Za-z]{2,4})([_-](?<script>[A-Za-z]{4}|[0-9]{3}))?([_-](?<country>[A-Za-z]{2}|[0-9]{3}))?([_-]x[_-](?<private>[A-Za-z0-9-_]+))?$
```

Comment: As I understand it, if using `-` as a literal character in a `[]` group, it needs to be the last character, otherwise it may be interpreted as the range separator, as in `a-z`.

Comment: To clarify, that means that the last `[A-Za-z0-9-_]` would be better as `[A-Za-z0-9_-]`. However, the current arrangement may work because the `9` is already part of the `0-9` range, and so the following `-` may not be mistaken for being part of another range.

Comment: FYI: Within an `input` element's `pattern` attribute, within a `[]` group, a lone `-` (not in a range) has to be escaped, as in `\-`, at least in Chrome, Edge and Firefox. This is not required for any other regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-z]{2}([_])?([A-Za-z]{2})?$
```

I used this regex and it works for locale only having optional '_' 
For example:
en,
de,
en_us,
en_US

So Regex works if the locale has only fixed two chars (only lowercase) 
or it has two chars (only lowercase) + _ + two chars (can be uppercase)

Comment: Please explain how this answers the question. Especially with the difference of `-` and `_`. Generally, answers with an explanation (in contrast to code-only answers like yours) help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Comment: @JanSršeň Nice edit, sorry for trumping it.

Comment: I meant the regex I provided is good to use if we have locales like I gave examples en, de, en_us, en_US 
I just sorted it from one of the answers which covers - and _ both even a more range.

Comment: So you agree that explaining your code is necessary. Please do so by [edit]ing your post, instead of hiding this vital information in a comment.